# Tips on implementing a DataStore in Android?

Tags: android, database, persistence, ipc

I am working on providing a data store on Android (one that does not use SQLite), starting with a single-app desktop version of our Java Library. The ideal solution will be:

- executed in its own process, providing access to other applications by some form of IPC
- persistent, and therefore the application using it will not lose data upon phone shutdown
- reasonably responsive

Using my client-server architecture background, my initial attempt was to use a `Service`, with which the other applications can communicate using `bindService` and other calls. The resulting had quality #1 (and #3 to some extent) above, but it was not clear to me as to when to write all this data back to the filesystem, especially since it turns out that the `onDestroy()` method is not guaranteed to be called, especially during machine shutdown. Using Alarms to periodically save data is not a good solution either, since it might lead to uncommitted changes when the process is killed.

Now, I am thinking of using a `ContentProvider`, which I believe is also the philosophically best way. However problem #2 still remains: how can I guarantee that uncommitted changes are not remaining when the system shuts down, while not sacrificing on performance by using naive techniques such as writing to filesystem on each operation? I wonder how the native SQLite implementation achieves it?

Please suggest the proper way to go about doing this. This should not be as hard as I am finding it to be :).

Thanks.